# Cloudformation to Change Ec2 Instance State

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently I am designing Cloudformation template to create an EC2 instance and monitor the EC2 instance, enable detail monitoring using cloudwatch and change the instance state to stop once it reached the metrics,

I am able to create a instance able to enable metrics but I am not able to change the instance state to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the EC2 instance state to `stop` when a specified [`AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html) Resouce transitions into `ALARM` state, you can accomplish this using the special `arn:aws:automate:region:ec2:stop` ARN in the [`AlarmActions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-alarmaction) property for the alarm.

Note however that before this will work, you need to manually create at least one stop, terminate, or reboot alarm using the Amazon EC2 or CloudWatch console to create the **`EC2ActionsAccess`** IAM role. After this IAM role is created, you can create stop, terminate, or reboot alarms using the CloudFormation resource directly. See the [`PutMetricAlarm` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi @Sundaravel, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official docs for the [CloudFormation AWS::EC2::Instance resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html), this functionality does not seem to be supported.

You can always delete the resource from your sources, but that would - of course - terminate the instance, which I don't think is what you're looking for.

Perhaps one workaround would be to change the `UserData` section, so that it runs something along the lines of `shutdown -h now` while also changing the [InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-instanceinitiatedshutdownbehavior) to `stop`.

Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Mr.Gsaslis , thanks for your reply, I am trying to do using "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"

Comment: hmmm... i'm not sure what you mean?