# How to add notification action in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to add notification action in cloud watch through service catalog, I created new SNS topic and refer the topic in cloud watch actions section it failed, and also when ever I am creating cloud watch action through service catalog it ask me to enable IAM to make action even though I manually created alarm to stop an EC2 instance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is a bit difficult to understand what you are describing. Could you possibly Edit your question to provide more details, including samples of the configuration you have used? It's also a bit difficult to understand *where* you are configuring things (in SNS? in Service Catalog? in CloudWatch?). Any additional detail you can provide would improve the likelihood of you receiving a useful answer.

Comment: Below is my code actually I am trying to achieve send notification when the instance state change to stop or terminate.                                                      
        "AlarmActions": [
          {"Fn::Join": [ ":", "arn:aws:automate:us-west-2:ec2:stop:",
              
          {"Ref": "MySNSTopic"     },
          {"Ref": "IAMPD464"

Comment: Ah! It appears you are wishing to create a CloudFormation template that deploys the alarm. Have you attempted to create the Alarm + Action manually to confirm it works before writing it as a CloudFormation template (that can be run via Service Catalog)? The IAM permissions are required to grant CloudWatch permissions to terminate the EC2 instance.

Comment: Hi John thanks for your reply I can able to create alarm with action manually and its works, I am getting problem when I am trying to create the same through cloud formation, I can able to create Alarm but it won't make the action and notification.

Comment: Have you created the `EC2ActionsAccess` Role? It is mentioned on [Create Alarms to Stop, Terminate, Reboot, or Recover an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html). What errors messages are you receiving (and when)?

Comment: Yes I created EC2ActionsAccess role, I not getting error I am not able to that particular IAM role for the created action, when I manually editing the created cloud watch alarm it have check box option to "Use existing IAM role" I need to enable that option through cloud formation template

Comment: Ah! Try this: [Cloudformation to Change Ec2 Instance State](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249382/cloudformation-to-change-ec2-instance-state)

Comment: Hi John the answer in the link was asked by myself only

Comment: Ah! Then how is that question different to this one? You accepted the answer on that question.